# How can I read the contents of a linked script into a String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am able to select a linked script element. Is there a way to read the contents into a string?

I have jQuery available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do ajax request and pass script url (src attribute). Server will return js source. Example:

```
var script = $('selector');
var src = script.attr('src');

if (src.indexOf('://') == -1) {
    src = document.location.href.substr(0, document.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + src;
}

$.get(src, {}, function(data){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for another way that didn't involve an additional call, but it seems like none exists.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried this before but if you get the script such as

```
$(scriptselector).text()
```

Edited.

Just tried it and it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/UG3hB/

Edit #2:

As Intersteller_Coder pointed out this will not work with linked jsfiles.  You can always request the js file via AJAX.

Comment: that does work - I've used it to read GLSL shaders from the page.

Comment: Not for linked javascript files, that would work for javascript embedded within the page.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder .. Like I said "Never tried this before"... but its good to know.  Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the script is embedded or linked.

For embedded javascript you could do

```
var test = $('script').eq( index_here ).text();
```

For an external javascript file with a source attribute, you could perform an ajax request and get the contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div/>").append($("#myAnchor")).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just get the innerText or innerHTML from the element reference.